# Orthogonal of the orthogonal?

Tags: analysis

I have this question how to prove that in a Hilbert space we have always  :

$$(E^\perp)^\perp\subset\overline{E}$$

Comment: You know that the perp of something is closed, by continuity, and you know that it contains $E$, almost trivially, so it follows by definition.

Comment: it's closed yes but, but contains $E$ i don't think so

Comment: $x\in E^{\perp \perp}$ if and only if $(x, E^{\perp})=0$, so it clearly contains $E$.

Answer (score 1):

It is (as in most such cases) Hahn-Banach. Suppose that this is not true. Then there is $x\in \bar E $ sich that $x\not\in E^{\perp\perp} $. Choose $y\in X $ such that $\langle y, x\rangle = 1$ and $y \perp E^{\perp \perp} $. Then $y\perp E $, continuity gives $y\perp \bar E $; contradiction.